# How Do You Treat a Specific Div or Section of a Layout as it's own self-contained Viewport?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am working with a responsive web layout I've diagrammed in the image below below.  Red areas are fixed on the screen, green areas are independently scrollable sections (blue = scrollbars).

[image: layout]

**I'm wondering - is there any way (without iframes) to take the main content section of this layout (the green area on the right) and treat it as if it was the viewport itself so that the contents and styles would work as if it were it's own independent full screen?**

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I'd like it to **be as easy as possible to just fit a 2nd website's content straight into this main content section without having to adjust all of the pages** to now fit into the narrower section of the site.

The **2nd site was built using twitter bootstrap for the scaffolding**, and since the containers are all created relative to someone's viewport size, they **do not fit neatly into the slightly narrower content area** (given the left sidebar) without having to adjust all of the scaffolding.  I'd rather not have to adjust everything on many pages and therefore, I'm looking for a hack to see if I can just make it fit (crossing my fingers that something exists!)

In addition, the **left sidebar is collapsible** - so there would be a case where the main content section would take up the entire width of the viewport.  Hence, I would want it to dynamically adjust.

It seems like I have 3 options:

1. Go through each page of the 2nd site and **rework all of the scaffolding in each page** to ensure they work with a slightly narrower section, essentially treating the left sidebar as the first span column, and then adjusting the entirety of the site to work within the remaining width.  **This option doesn't really work** because if the sidebar is collapsed, then the main content area takes up the full-width and would now be narrower.
2. Use iFrames - I am NOT considering this due to all of the implications.
3. **Somehow treat the main content area as its own viewport so that all of the scaffolding adjusts to whatever size it is, as if it were the viewport itself, or a full screen .**

Is this possible somehow?

Is there perhaps an alternative solution that might be even better?

Thanks!

Comment: "*and since the containers are all created relative to someone's viewport size*" - How is this done? Are the container dimensions set based on the viewport dimensions? Does Twitter's bootstrap do this?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yes, it is done through media queries to make it responsive.  See here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: Not answering because I haven't tested any of this: Have you tried an SVG `foreignObject`?

Comment: No, you cannot designate an arbitrary HTML element as its own self-contained viewport.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, figured it wasn't going to be that easy.

Comment: @robertc no, I haven't tried it because of the lack of IE support.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: SVG has approximately [81% browser support](http://caniuse.com/svg), do you specifically need IE8 support?

Comment: @robertc that's a fair point and it's not specifically about needing certain browser support- it's more about finding a solution that works across the board since this is an entire page we're dealing with.  When I think about browser support, it's usually for small features that I can find a graceful fall-back for.  In this case, it's kind of hard for me to find a graceful fall-back for the entirety of a page :)

Comment: Can't the fallback simply be to open a popup window of the required dimensions?

Comment: @robertc unfortunately no.  The point was to have it be a seamless experience- it's supposed to be one site.  A pop-up with the main content while the navigation and main toolbar are in a different window does not really make for a fantastic experience.  I was just trying to find a shortcut- a quick way to not have to rework all of the scaffolding to make it fit for now so I could ship as quickly as possible, but I'm realizing I'm going to have to do it anyway.  Thanks again for your input :)